# Using SQL to SELECT from multiple Excel tables and INSERT the data into an Access table

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Okay I am simultaneously trying to learn VBA and SQL so please excuse me if this question seems dumb. I am trying to pull data from multiple excel files that meet certain conditions then insert that data into an Access table. We are trying to automate some label printing and the first step is to pull the data from these multiple excel sheets and insert it into the access sheet.

Could someone just give me some ideas on how to do this? I'm coding from Access, I figured out how to SELECT the data from one sheet and then INSERT it into the Access table but not how to do it with multiple tables. Also these excel files may have the same column names across along with multiple sheets of tables in each excel file.

Here is some code I used for the pulling of data from a single sheet

```
dim UDA817 as string
UDA817 = "UDA00817_00"

//'MARK_PER_UDA_00817 is a field name in my MASTER table

 sql2 = "INSERT INTO MASTER ([MARK_PER_UDA_00817]) " _
        & "SELECT [F4] " _
        & "FROM " & UDA817 & ";"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options on how to approach this, but I think the simplest one is going to be using the UNION operator.  Try this:

```
Option Compare Database
```

Option Explicit

Dim UDA817 As String
UDA817 = "UDA00817_00"

//'MARK_PER_UDA_00817 is a field name in my MASTER table

sql2 = "INSERT INTO MASTER ([MARK_PER_UDA_00817]) " _
        & "SELECT [F4] " _
        & "FROM " & UDA817 & ";" & _
        "UNION " & _
        "SELECT Field 1, Field 2 " & _
        "FROM  tblTable2 "

'// Utilize the UNION operator to concatenate 2 or more SELECT strings